# Getting encoded response in Rest Assured but in Postman it gives correct response

Tags: java, postman, rest-assured

In my Rest Assured I am getting the JSON response but in some fields of that response are coming in an encoded form, I tried to hit the same URL get request in Postman and I got the correct response without any encoding.

**This is the following code I tried in Rest Assured:**

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/";
        String GetResponse=given().contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .when().get("airlines")
                .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8").extract().response().asString();
        
        System.out.println(GetResponse);
```

**This is the output I got in Rest Assured:**

```
UJhVJKwXQk7LMTkgimTZXEncZQCAAGlcdkJMrIgES9R3E8wGh6E6AUVcW4LQaABDzCwE2YyrCYCAEARLyJLaJYUgQCApMGK4gHcTbEMILieQNoV7lBcTYA2AD2JcibsIvmsF7maKRQwTALkDEArgMLpEtiSbAfMF7jUR2Ckl1GshodgEkFigYE2AAAQIYWAQDyC2QCGshDAYCHsQFw1DYTYDC5IFDbuKw0mJvl1AEgk0tzOVRvQqnQq1tI5dWBLqPYdOlVqv2I373odtHAwjnP2n+B2wp5aEvJZHDSwMUrz9p/gdCo2VkrI64wK5EZ1rHLTTi7M6IxTVxSgTGTi7Mg1sMItNDsAgAAAAAAAAABDABAAAAhisAAAwJCxVhAQ4jjNxdmUS0BqmpLITRkm4s1jNSWYCsIpiALjExIBhcAAAAEArAUSwP/9k=","slogan":"I am from india","head_quaters":"bombay","website":"hrp.gov","established":"2001"},{"id":1454889993,"name":"9","country":"Sri Lanka","logo":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9b/Qatar_Airways_Logo.svg/sri_lanka.png","slogan":"From Sri Lanka","head_quaters":"Katunayake, Sri Lanka","website":"www.srilankaairways.com","established":"1990"}
```

**I tried to hit the same URL in postman I got the correct output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 999999,
        "name": "qwertyu",
        "country": "asdfghj",
        "logo": "sdfgh",
        "slogan": "zxcvbnm",
        "head_quaters": "hsdfghj",
        "website": "zxcvbnm,",
        "established": "45645"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Air India",
        "country": "India",
        "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e3/Air_India_Logo.svg/250px-Air_India_Logo.svg.png",
        "slogan": "Your Palace in the Sky",
        "head_quaters": "Airlines House, New Delhi, India",
        "website": "https://www.airindia.in",
        "established": "1990"
    },
```

**These were the headers in postman**

[image: Postman Header]

Comment: That are two different respnses. can you share a example from the same request? BTW: The firstpart looks like a base64 encoded string

Comment: @Jens 1st response is from the rest assured where the 2nd response is of postman and that is my question that why they are coming different when same api is being hit.

Comment: Please show also the url of postman call

Comment: @Jens https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines its my base url and http request is of GET

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing wrong here. What you got is a part of response and it cannot show all info b/c of the limit of console max length. And your api have a very very big response, you can double check in browser `https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines`

[image]

To view response in json format, use `.prettyPrint()` method.

```java
given().get("https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines").prettyPrint();
```

[image]

Comment: using the above method it shows the incomplete json output

Comment: Of course, it is. Can’t show all b/c of the limit of tool, not relate to Rest-Assured.